# Sound is not coming in Salesforce1 app

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps

We have created one lightning component for Salesforce1 app. Everything is working, but sound is not working.

Do anyone know, why sound is not working/coming in Salesforce1 app?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is the sound coming from? Most external resources are blocked by the CSP of Lightning.

Comment: We are just using sound tag of HTML5 markup and sound file is stored in static resource.
Also, it is working in iPhone but not in Android app (Salesforce1 app).
Even if i try it in Android Chrome browser, Sound is not coming.